# Alert when delete button is pressed is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing Inventory tracking system, and I want there is an alert say "Are you sure?" when the delete button is pressed. It work when you press delete, but the alert not showing up.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>View Records</title>

</head>

<body>
<p><a href="Search_Vendor.php"><img src="img/SEARCH2.jpg" width="25" 
height="27" align='left'></a></p>



<div class="dropdown"><img class="dropbtn" img src="img/dropdown.png"    
width="44" height="47"></img>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="home3.php">HOMEPAGE</a>
<a href="New_Vendor.php">ADD NEW RECORD</a>
<a href="Print_Vendor.php">PRINT</a>
</div>
</div> 

<center> <h2> VENDOR RECORD </h2> </center>

<?php

// connect to the database
include('connection.php');

// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendor") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

// display data in table

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='20' cellspacing='0' align ='center'";
echo "<tr>  <th>Vendor ID</th> <th>Vendor Name</th> <th>Contact No </th>   
<th>Address</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table

    echo "<tr>

                <td align = center>".$row['Vendor_ID']."</th> 
                <td align = center>".$row['Vendor_Name']."</th>
                <td align = center>".$row['Contact_No']."</th> 
                <td align = center>".$row['Address']."</th> 

                <td><a href='Update_Vendor.php?ID=$row[ID]
                &Vendor_ID=$row[Vendor_ID]
                &Vendor_Name=$row[Vendor_Name]
                &Contact_No=$row[Contact_No]
                &Address=$row[Address]'>Update</a></td>

                <td>
                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"          
                href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=<?= $row[ID] ?>">Delete</a>
                </td>

        </tr>";
}   

//close the table
echo "</table>";

?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a link for you clicked element, it's likely that it is trying to actually open the link address before your code can run. Use `e.preventDefault();` with and event handler like below to avoid that behaviour:

#### [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/q50hdhr9/2/)

```
<a class="delete" href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=123">Delete</a>

$(function() {

  $('.delete').click(function(e) {
    var $this=$(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      // code to delete stuff
      window.location=$this.attr('href');
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: Im so sorry, i really really new in php, what do you mean by using `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: Its not PHP its javascript. When you click on a link, the default behaviour is to immediately navigate to the page at the address in the link's `href` attribute. In your case, `Delete_Vendor.php?ID=1231`. When you click your link, you are going to that page before your confirm code has a chance to run, using an event handler and calling `e.preventDefault()` *prevents that default behaviour* and allows the code to run, then if the user chooses ok, we manually redirect to the href page with `window.location=$this.attr('href');`

Answer (score -1):

I found this example on the net... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question other than they both use `onclick` and `confirm`

Comment: @DelightedD0D sure... look at the code: var r = confirm.... and it would be a solution....

Comment: Please explain how this addresses a flaw in the OP's code that might be causing their issue.